# how to send selected data to php file with out click any button

Tags: php, ajax

Hi every one i would like to ask to:
I have a selected menu with some option

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I need to when i select any option this option sent to another file with out any clicked button just choose it. how to do this with ajax

Comment: make an onchange event to select tag and call the ajax function in it

Answer (score 3):

In this example, `change() function` is used to send data from one page to another using **AJAX**.

**somepage.php**

```
<select class="Car">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 

<div class='ShowSelectedCar'>

</div>

<script>
$('.Car').change(function(){
    var Car= $('.Car').val();
    $.ajax({url:"AjaxCar.php?Car="+Car,cache:false,success:function(result){
        alert(Car);
        $('.ShowSelectedCar').html(result);
    }});
});
</script>
```

**AjaxCar.php**

```
<?
$car=$_GET['Car'];

echo $car;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but after select car type i go to AjaxCar php file and refresh, the selected car doesn't appear why ?

Comment: @M.Ahmed this is because when you refresh the AjaxCar.php page, it recreates the page from new. Unless you have stored the chosen value of car, either through the server, or in the user's browser, it will not be available to the re-created page.